# Is $\frac{\rm d}{\rm d\omega(t)}\int_{t_0}^t\omega(t')\rm dt'=\int_{t_0}^t\frac{\rm d \omega(t')}{\rm d\omega(t')}dt'=t_0-t?$

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, error-propagation

I'm trying to calculate an error propagation, but the expression in the most LHS of the equation in the title crops up. Are you allowed to simply exchange the order so that the operations cancel?

$\omega(t)$ is a simple angular velocity that is a dataset obtained from an experiment with a pendulum.

> **EDIT:** Apparently it cannot be done. I only know $\omega(t)$ numerically (it's a data-array) - any ideas for how to calculate an error propagation that involves this term?

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Thomas.E2.80.93Fermi_kinetic_energy_functional) example that might be helpful, but I'm a bit in the deep end here, and Leibniz's rule doesn't seem to apply here.

If this error propagation could somehow be obtained numerically, that would also be very helpful!

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: No. Try it with $w(t) = t$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks! Any ideas on how to evaluating the error propagation expression then? I only know $\omega(t)$ numerically.

Comment: Unfortunately not unless it can be interpreted using chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that

$$\frac {\textrm d} {\textrm d \omega (t)} \int \limits _{t_0} ^t \omega(t') \ \textrm d t' = \omega (t) \frac {\textrm d t} {\textrm d \omega (t)} = \frac {\omega (t)} {\omega ' (t)} .$$

Now, having $t \mapsto \omega (t)$ numerically, compute $t \mapsto \omega' (t) = \frac {\omega (t+h) - \omega(t)} h$ numerically (for some chosen, small, fixed $h$) and this should be it.

The results used above are:

$$\frac {\textrm d} {\textrm d t} \int \limits _{f(t)} ^{g(t)} \varphi (t') \ \textrm d t' = \varphi \Big( g(t) \Big) g'(t) - \varphi \Big( (f(t) \Big) f'(t)$$

and, obviously,

$$\frac {\textrm d \omega} {\textrm d t} = \frac 1 {\frac {\textrm d t} {\textrm d \omega}}$$

(under the usual assumptions involving the existence of fractions etc.)

Comment: That's amazing, thanks! Do you mind explaining the steps a bit (or what theorems are used)? I'm familiar with numerical integration, but thanks anyway :)